# Android Alarm manager on specific date and time not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to set alarm for specific date and time using below code:

```
private lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager
  alarmManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("alarm", newAlarm)
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            2342,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

        val myAlarmDate = Calendar.getInstance()
        myAlarmDate.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
       // myAlarmDate[alarm?.year ?: 0, alarm?.month ?: 0, alarm?.hour ?: 0, alarm?.minute ?: 0, 0] =
            0
        myAlarmDate[2023, 9, 22, 10, 0] =0
        val alarmManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
```

alarmManager[AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myAlarmDate.timeInMillis] = pendingIntent

But it is not working/ triggering any alarm

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the alarm with one of the available methods for scheduling. Instantiating alone would not activate it.

For example:

```
...
val alarmManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
// set the alarm
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myAlarmDate.timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
...
```

Depending on your use case, you would use one of the several available methods in `AlarmManager` to set the alarm.

There can be one-time (e.g. `set()`) or repeating alarms (e.g. `setRepeating()`). When it comes to delivery precision, there can be exact (e.g. `setExact()`) or inexact alarms (e.g. `set()`).

To find out which one best suits your needs, I would recommend further reading about them in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) for `AlarmManager`.